# Examples that $f(\overline{E})\subsetneq\overline{f(E)}$ for continuous $f: X \to Y$ and subset $E\subset X$ (Baby Rudin Problem 4.2)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on the second part of problem 2 of chapter 4 in Rudin, and I was wondering if someone could check my example or, even if it's correct, maybe help me find a less trivial one.

The problem, as the title says, is to find a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ (where $X$, $Y$ are metric spaces) and subset $E\subset X$ such that $f(\overline{E})\subsetneq\overline{f(E)}$

The example I came up with is $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R} $, $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ and $E=\mathbb{N}$. So $E=\overline{E}$ and $f(E)=\{ {1\over n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and so $\overline{f(E)}=f(E)\cup\{0\}$

I was wondering if this is correct and if there is a more insightful example where $E$ is more interesting than a set of isolated points.

Comment: It's correct. I don't know if you'll find it more interesting, but $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $E = (0,\,\infty)$ is another easy example.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't the closure of $f(E)$ **in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$** itself? If he takes $Y=\mathbb{R}$ then yes, $\overline{f(E)}=f(E)\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Good observation, @AldoGuzmánSáenz, I didn't consider that the OP used $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ in the question. Of course we need $\mathbb{R}$ (or anything that contains $[0,1]$) as the codomain for my example.

Comment: So I can fix it if I just change the codomain to $\mathbb{R}$? Even if the function doesn't map to {0}?

Comment: @Robearz yes, it doesn't matter if the function doesn't map to $\{0\}$ (there are already lots of points in $\mathbb{R}$ not in the image of the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the inclusion function $f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ with $E=\mathbb Q$. Then clearly $\overline E=E$ so $f(\overline E)=E$, but $\overline {f(E)}=\mathbb R$.

Comment: isn't the closure of rationals the reals? not itself?

Comment: no @AnthonyColombo the closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Rational_Numbers_is_Real_Numbers

Comment: The closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb R$ is the result you are talking about. But that does not change the fact that the closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: oh I see the difference.  Thank you.

Comment: I like this example, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very natural examples. For instance
$$\exp(\overline{\mathbb{R}}) = (0,\infty) \quad \text{but} \quad \overline{\exp(\mathbb{R})} = [0,\infty)$$
since $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}$.

In fact, any continuous map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose domain is not a closed set will do.